# Search in bitbucket project for all folders with a particular name

Tags: search, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I want to search in a bitbucket project for all folders with the name "flockstructure". I ran the following command in the bitbucket search window--

project:MyProject flockstructure

Here MyProject is the name of the project which I want to search for the folder (flockstructure). However, this is returning the names of all the files having "flockstructure" in the name as well as all files have "flockstructure" in the content. Is there any way to limit the results so that it shows only the folders having the name flockstructure or atleast the files and folders having the name "flockstructure" and NOT show files having "flockstructure" in their content.

The below link didnt help either ==

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/search-in-bitbucket-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

Add `path:flockstructure` to limit results to "the files and folders having the name". The full query would be:

`project:MyProject path:flockstructure flockstructure`

Answer (score 0):

This page show search's syntax:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-search-syntax-814204781.html

In your case, for example

"my_keyword" project:MyProject path:file_1.txt

find a word 'my_keyword' in files with name 'file_1.txt' in all repos of project 'MyProject'